# Npm start throwing error during compilation

Tags: reactjs

When I compile my code below error occur:[Error Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80vCH.png)

why error occur during compilation process?

Comment: navigate into scripts folder and type node start.js

Comment: show your start.js file?